# How to get lists of all subsites and sites in powershell CSOM for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom

i want to input one site collection and want to get all the lists of that site as well as subsites. but i am unable to iterate through all subsites. Please suggest. I am using csom in powershell for SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 3):

The following PowerShell code with CSOM for your reference.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl= "http://sp2013/sites/team"
$username="administrator"
$password="**"
$domain="lz"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)

Try {
    #Function to Get all lists from the web
    Function Get-SPOList($Web)
    {
        #Get All Lists from the web
        $Lists = $Web.Lists
        $Context.Load($Lists)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get all lists from the web  
        ForEach($List in $Lists)
        {
            #Get the List Name
            Write-host $List.Title
        }
    }

    #Function to get all webs from given URL
    Function Get-SPOWeb($WebURL)
    {
        #Set up the context
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebURL)
        $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

        $Web = $context.Web
        $Context.Load($web)
        #Get all immediate subsites of the site
        $Context.Load($web.Webs) 
        $Context.executeQuery()

        #Call the function to Get Lists of the web
        Write-host "Processing Web :"$Web.URL
        Get-SPOList $Web

        #Iterate through each subsite in the current web
        foreach ($Subweb in $web.Webs)
        {
            #Call the function recursively to process all subsites underneaththe current web
            Get-SPOWeb($SubWeb.URL)
        }
    }

    #Call the function to get all sites
    Get-SPOWeb $SiteUrl
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following powershell script.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
cls

$webApp=Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepointwebapplication"
foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
{
    #Write-Host $siteColl.URL
    foreach($web in $siteColl.AllWebs)
    {
        Write-Host $web.URL $web.ParentWeb.URL
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this provides empty values for `$web.URL` if it's the root site. And it will iterate through each site collection, but because you're doing `$siteColl.AllWebs`, every time you do a site collection, you're re-running through EVERY web on the site, not just the webs under that SC. You should do: `foreach ($site in $siteColl) { ... }` and then get each collection of webs, specifically: `$subsites = Get-SPWeb -site $site` and then iterate: `foreach ($web in $subsites) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The following CSOM will work to iterate through all the subsites and its List/Libraries. You can modify it as per your requirement

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.Load(web.Webs);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Web subWeb in web.Webs)
{
   string newpath = subWeb.Url;
   Console.WriteLine(subWeb.Title + "-------" + subWeb.Url);

   ClientContext clientContext2 = new ClientContext(subWeb.Url);
   var libraries = clientContext2.LoadQuery(clientContext2.Web.Lists);
   clientContext2.ExecuteQuery();

   foreach (List list in libraries)
   {
      string libTitle = list.Title;
      Console.WriteLine("  --List/Library: " + libTitle);
   }
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks Ankit, But we cant use lambda expressions to load objects in powershell. Is there any other way without which we can access same output without using website => website.Webs, website => website.Title?

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi:  I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job.

```
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell }

$site = $null
$site = Get-SPSite "https://contoso.com"

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    Write-Host "  Web:" $web.Url
    foreach($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        Write-host "    List:" $list.Title
    }
    $web.Dispose()
}

$site.Dispose()
Write-Host "End" -b DarkGreen -f Green
```